# Discover function to discontinuity.

Tags: functions

Discover function  $2x - \tan(x) = 0$ to discontinuity.

And find discontinuity point.

I get this $lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)} = \pm\infty$

It's mean $x = {\pi\over2} + \pi*n; n \in  \mathbb{Z}$ and $x = {3\pi\over2} + \pi*n; n \in  \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

the domain of $\tan x$:

$$\{x\in \mathbb R:\pi\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)<x<\pi\left(n+\frac 3 2\right)\quad n\in \mathbb Z\}$$

**Hint 2:**

$\tan x$ periodic in $x$ with period $\pi$

**Hint 3:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/2^{-}}\tan x=?$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to -\pi/2^{+}}\tan x=?$$

**Hint 4:** $\tan x$ graph:

[image]